# azure smtp tls certificate invalid

Tags: azure, smtp, starttls

I am developing a web application which will send mails to users. I have configured the SmtpClient in the web.config file like this:

```
    <network enableSsl="true" host="xd2.serverdomain.org" port="25" userName="<username>" password="<password>" />
```

On my local machine everything works well. When hosting the application on Azure I get an error, that the certificate is invalid.

Can anyone tell me why it is working on my local machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the certificate signed by a common certification authority? Have you remoted to the VM and looked at the certificate chain?

Comment: Since I am just having a normal website I did not try this, but that is a good idea. The certificate is signed by PositiveSSL ...